# How to convert JSON string to JSON Object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, serialization

I use the `JavaScriptSerializer` class of ASP.net to serialize my object and return it to the client side.  How can I deserialize the string using JavaScript?

Comment: Obligatory link: [json.org](http://json.org)

Comment: "JSON Object" is kind of an oxymoron. It's either an object, or a JSON string. Both not both at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using jQuery already, you'll be happy to know that you can parse a JSON string with [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

If you aren't using jQuery and don't want to, you can always use the wonderful [`JSON.parse`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) or [`json_parse`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), written by none other than [Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/) himself.

I would [avoid `eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) if it isn't necessary.

Comment: +1 because ... 1) *Someone else* has already solved this problem 2) *Someone else* has already solved this problem in a good way.

Comment: Except that jQuery.parseJSON() doesn't serialize .Net DateTime objects into jscript date objects. Instead they're simply deserialized to strings.

Comment: @jlafay JSON (as per the JSON specification) doesn't support `Date` objects. Since `jQuery.parseJSON` will parse a valid `JSON` string into a JavaScript object, I would not expect it to deserialize `Date` objects at all regardless of their format.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to propose ... **do nothing**. This assumes the serialized result is returned *with* the page and/or an additional HTML fragment.

```
// In some JavaScript area somewhere in the ASP page
var myObject = <%= JSONIfiedObjectResult %>;
```

*This works and is valid because JSON is a subset of JavaScript literals*. Note that I did not put quotes around the `<%= %>`.

If the de-serialization is the result on an AJAX call returning JSON, etc, then see Zack's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty trivial -- just do

```
var x = eval(theString);
```

which should get everything except ASP.Net's unique serialization of `DateTime`, which is not supported by "real" JSON and is an ASP.Net extension.  To use ASP.Net's deserializer, make sure you include an `<asp:ScriptManager>` tag in your page, and call

```
var x = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(theString);
```

which will invoke the special Date handling and probably get you better security.

Comment: @pst What? The alternative is there -- and if you use that alternative you get Date handling thrown in.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty standard, not so safe:

```
eval('(' + json + ')');
```

Kind of cool thing that jQuery does, still not very safe:

```
(new Function('return ' + json))();
```

Comment: @pst Using `window.JSON.parse` and never working with IE 6 or 7.